# spark-submit: --jars does not work

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am building metrics system for Spark Streaming job, in the system, the metrics are collected in each executor, so a metrics source (a class used to collect metrics) needs to be initialized in each executor.

The metrics source is packaged in a jar, when submitting a job, the jar is sent from local to each executor using the parameter '--jars', however, the executor starts to initialize the metrics source class before the jar arrives, as a result, it throws class not found exception.

It seems that if the executor could wait until all resources are ready, the issue will be resolved, but I really do not know how to do it.

Is there anyone facing the same issue?

PS: I tried using HDFS (copy the jar to HDFS, then submit the job and let the executor load class from a path in HDFS), but it fails. I checked the source code, it seems that the class loader can only resolve local path.

Here is the log, you can see that the jar is added to classpath at 2016-01-15 18:08:07, but the initialization starts at 2016-01-15 18:07:26

> INFO  2016-01-15 18:08:07 org.apache.spark.executor.Executor: Adding
>   file:/var/lib/spark/worker/worker-0/app-20160115180722-0041/0/./datainsights-metrics-source-assembly-1.0.jar
>   to class loader
>
> ERROR 2016-01-15 18:07:26 Logging.scala:96 -
>   org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem: Source class
>   org.apache.spark.metrics.PerfCounterSource cannot be instantiated

Here is the command I use:

```
spark-submit --verbose \
 --jars /tmp/datainsights-metrics-source-assembly-1.0.jar \ 
 --conf "spark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties" \
 --class org.microsoft.ofe.datainsights.StartServiceSignalPipeline \
 ./target/datainsights-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Comment: can you post the command you tried.?

Comment: It seems that the jar is loaded to the classpath, but the process is quite slow due to network latency. As a result, I encountered another issue, I have updated the question. pls see it for details.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of couple of Options: -

1. Create a Fat Jar File, which includes main classes and dependencies.
2. If dependencies are used only by executors and not by the Driver, then you can explicitly add jar files using `SparkConf.setJars(....)` or in case it is used by driver too, then you can also use command line option `--driver-class-path` for configuring Driver classpath.
3. Try configure it in Spark-default.conf using following parameters: -

   ```
   spark.executor.extraClassPath=<classapth>
   spark.executor.extraClassPath=<classapth>
   ```

No matter what you do, I would suggest to fix the network latency, otherwise it will hurt the performance of Spark jobs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this method, the jar is sent to each executor, but the executor starts initialization instantly before the jar arrive executor. Maybe network is really a issue, but I think Spark should have a function to make sure all resources arrive at executor before executor starts initialization